# How exactly does \newcommand work?

Tags: macros

Based on this code snippet, I concluded that `\newcommand` commands work by string substitution before expansion:

```
\newcommand{\double}[1]{#1#1}
\newcounter{dummy}

\thedummy \double{\stepcounter{dummy}} \thedummy
```

which outputs `0 2`, indicating that `\stepcounter` is appearing twice after `\double` is expanding. So it's substituted before being expanded/executed.

However, the following code:

```
\newcommand{\append}[1]{#1long}

\newcommand{\mypi}{3.1}
\newcommand{\mypilong}{3.14159}
\append{\mypi}{4159}
```

ouptuts `3.1long` instead of `3.14159` (which you'd expect from string substitution), indicating that `\mypi` was expanded prior to being substituted.

What do I have wrong?

Comment: `#1long` does not get replaced by `\mypilong`, but by the *five* tokens `\mypi•l•o•n•g` (the bullets are used to show the distinct tokens).

Comment: @daleif Sorry, it was a typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX doesn't have the concept of “string”. It only works with *tokens*.

The replacement text of `\append` consists of a “parameter token”, that will get substituted at call time with the actual argument, followed by four tokens `l`, `o`, `n` and `g`.

TeX works with tokens and will never “append” them to control sequence names: it will *never* fuse together two tokens. So when you call `\append{\mypi}` you get

```
\mypi•l•o•n•g
```

(where the bullets are used to mark the boundaries between tokens). Next `\mypi` is replaced by its definition and you get

> 3.1long

The `{4159}` part will be read in next and the final output will be

> 3.1long4159

---

Your `\double` is also a bit problematic. I guess that the proper code you used is

```
\newcommand{\double}[1]{#1#1}
```

because `\newcommand{\double}[1]{#1}{#1}` would produce an error for a misplaced `#`.

---

Is it possible to define `\append` so that `\append{\mypi}` expands `\mypilong`? Yes, in various ways. One is

```latex
\newcommand{\gobblebackslash}[1]{}
\newcommand{\append}[1]{\csname\expandafter\gobblebackslash\string#1long\endcsname}
```

Explanation:

- we want to build a control sequence name from various parts, so `\csname...\endcsname` is needed;
- we can use `\string\mypi` to get the macro name, but there would be the backslash;
- so we strip the backslash off by expanding `\string\mypi` first and then letting `\gobblebackslash` do its job of gobbling one token.

Does this contradict the statement that tokens are never fused together? No. The primitive `\csname` expands to a single symbolic token build with the tokens it finds until the matching `\endcsname`.

**Note.** The code above implicitly assumes that the value of `\escapechar` is the usual one.

Comment: Thanks, this makes much more sense now.
If I understand correctly, all the tokens between `\csname` and `\endcsname` are converted into strings and concatenated, then the block of tokens as a whole is considered to expand to a command-token with that name (with \ in front, as it's a command token).
I'm not sure what `\expandafter` does, however.

Comment: @user218660 There is no string. Between `\csname` and `\endcsname` only character tokens should remain (after macro expansion). `\expandafter` expands the token after the immediately following one, in this case it jumps over `\gobblebackslash` and expands `\string`, which results in the five character tokens `\•m•y•p•i`. The name `\string` might be misleading, but it just converts a token to the character tokens that make up its name.

Comment: Right. I meant "string" as in a sequence of tokens which are all just characters, as opposed to command tokens.

So for example, even if you didn't need to remove the backslash, you would still need the `\string` in front of the `\mypi` (or `#1` more generally)? And without `\expandafter`, the `\gobblebackslash` would delete `\string`, leaving you with `\mypi•l•o•n•g`, which has one non-character, which would cause an error?